# Facebook inline video sharing with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, video, heroku, facebook-opengraph

I've been looking around for a bit but I can't seem to find any information on how to achieve what I want.

Basically I have a page which displays a gif and offers the possibility to share it on facebook. I tried to make this work with the gif file directly but after a lot of trial and a lot of errors I gave up on this idea and instead, decided I might as well make it so the page would appear as a video on facebook since I already have a 15second long video generated from the gif for instagram.

The problem is when I do this I keep ending up with this result

[image]

but I'm trying to do an inline video sharing (like youtube does)

I think I need a shockwave player but I have no idea where to begin, my video file being an mp4 and all.

I can't find any information on how to this using heroku + ruby on rails

any links would be appreciated.

here are the metatags I used:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="url_of_the_page">
<meta property="og:title" content="event_name">
<meta property="og:description" content="event_place_and_time">
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other">
<meta property="og:image" content="secure_url_of_remote_thumbnail">
<meta property="og:video" content="secure_url_of_remote_mp4">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="secure_url_of_remote_mp4">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="960">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="1280">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site_name">
```

Thanks for any help

[Facebook Open Graph Debugger Tool For The Page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hooop.fr%2Ftest-cartier-declaration%2F40580)

Comment: Inline video works with swf _or_ mp4, you don’t need both. Have you used the FB debug tool to clear the cache after you made changes, and to check whether it reports any errors?

Comment: @CBroe I have used the facebook debugger tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hooop.fr%2Ftest-cartier-declaration%2F40580 it doesn't raise any warnings

Comment: Try with a video hosted on an “normal” server first - those Amazon buckets often come with restrictions when it comes to access by “bots” etc., and need careful configuration in those regards.

Comment: I was looking around (because I don't have any normal server video since I'm on heroku to test) and I can't find any information on how to make S3 play nice with facebook for videos or clue towards that do you have any links that explain the problem between S3 and FB ?

Comment: @CBroe since I'm on heroku I tried adding a route which would download the file on the server temporarily and use `Base64.encode64(open(video_url) {|io| io.read})` to serve it just like a local file in a page where I placed new metatags but to no avail facebook still doesn't put it inline.

Comment: @CBroe I've added one of the generated mp4 videos to my asset pipeline and tried again and nothing changed. I'm really at a loss here