# Facebook Open Graph Object ignores attributes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've been trying for ages to find a solution to post my page as an inline video to facebook.

I've tried multiple meta-tags to no avail (it displays the image thumbnail and to the right the title/description/website).

I've tried using flow player to try using `og:video:type:application/x-shockwave-flash` but once again it showed the same exact result when attempting to share.

I've now been looking into facebook graph api for possible answers.

I thought I had something in custom open graph stories but I'm using the API v2.10 and it's been removed since 2.8 and completely removed from past versions of the API since october 2017, so that won't be a solution.

I then looked into the [Open Graph Stories Object API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api). Once again I thought I had something but now I am stuck because the example code on the page (using curl) doesn't work no matter what I do

```bash
curl \
  -X POST \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/app/objects/video.other"  \
  -F "access_token=APP_TOKEN" \
  -F "object={
    'description':'This is a description',
    'title':'Test Video Object',
    'video':'secure_url_to_video_on_AWS\',
    'url':'secure_url_to_page_on_my_website'
  }"
=> {"id":"OBJECT_ID"}
```

```bash
curl https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID\?access_token\=\{APP_TOKEN\}
=> {
  "created_time":"date",
  "title":"Test Video Object",
  "type":"video.other",
  "id":"OBJECT_ID"
}
```

and when I attempt to delete it as such I get an error

```bash
curl -X DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID\?access_token\=\{APP_TOKEN\}
=> {
  "error":{
    "message":"Unsupported delete request. Object with ID 'OBJECT_ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api",
    "type":"GraphMethodException",
    "code":100,
    "error_subcode":33,
    "fbtrace_id":"Cbec0ormiGq"
  }
}
```

So Basically 3 questions:

1) Why won't facebook save the other attributes except the title and type ?

2) The Object obviously exists since I can search it so why does it say it doesn't when I attempt to delete it (same result by the way using the object browser on their developper website) ?

3) Any ideas on how to share my page and make it appear as an inline video ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Open Graph story objects are not the way to go here ... if you just want to share the link to your page, that is not an Open Graph story to begin with. The way to embed videos so that they can play in newsfeed is via OG meta tags, so you got to follow up on your question on that from yesterday, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48565722/1427878

Comment: I've done everything you suggested already on that question @CBroe that is why I was looking into the Open Graph story objects since they seemed like something that might work which is why here I'm trying to understand them better and understand also why the objects don't seem to create normally (even if it won't help my issue I'm interested in making it work) I've also send a couple of replies to you on that question.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603909/facebook-open-graph-ogvideo-tag-for-youtube-videos, it looks like Facebook might be deliberately limiting this these days, to keep the user’s news feed “cleaner” ...

Comment: Hi @CBroe Could you post this as an answer, after having read the links shared on this I think I can close this question since there most likely won't be any solution coming from facebook to this. Hopefully they will upgrade the instagram API in exchange to allow direct sharing from websites or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper Open Graph meta tags would be the way to implement this - but it looks like Facebook is in the process of phasing this feature out.

This question [Facebook Open Graph og:video tag for YouTube videos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48603909/1427878) refers to a bug report on the FB developers site, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1963535797258090/, and there they say,

> It looks like this behavior is actually by design.
>
> In our efforts to make News Feed an even more visual and engaging place to connect, we have been introducing new design updates in News Feed beginning in August 2017.
>
> As part of these updates and to provide a consistent experience across desktop and mobile, external video link posts (both paid and organic) on desktop will look and function similar to other link posts. People will now tap on the links to go off of Facebook to watch videos instead of watching within News Feed — mirroring the experience available for such posts on mobile.

---

Not sure that’s going to happen for all content publishers at the same time. Facebook usually rolls out such updates gradually, so it might still work for some, while you might not be able to get it working now for any new pages/articles you share.