# facebook og:video not working

Tags: html, facebook, meta

I have .mp4, and am trying to post using meta tags for content of post.

The Facebook Debugger agrees I have the following..

```
<meta property="og:type"     content="video.other">
<meta property="og:title"    content="This is the title for a test post">
<meta property="fb:app_id"   content="<app_id>">
<meta property="og:description" content="Test">
<meta property="og:video"       content="https://<url_for_mp4>">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://<url_for_mp4>">
<meta property="og:video:type"       content="video/mp4">
<meta property="og:video:width"      content="1200">
<meta property="og:video:height"     content="630">
```

When rendering this Facebook just shows the title & description

Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48603909/1427878 refers to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1963535797258090/, and the latter suggests Facebook might have started to limit the availability of this feature ...

Comment: It would be nice if Facebook made some reference to this in their developer documentation / scraper!  Adding video's to posts by directly uploading them still works fine (in UK).